# Cut out a shape from a UIImage with a blurred edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage

How would I cut out a shape (indicated by the grey outline in pic A), with a blurred edge, so that it can be placed upon another image? I would prefer to use a programmatically described shape, rather than an image mask.

[image: cat with blurred face]

Comment: any answer ? I have the code for cropping the oval shape from and image and merging it on to the other image.. Fading the edges is what I need !!